# Welcome file ignores security constraint

Tags: jsf, servlets, security-constraint, welcome-file

my **web.xml**:

```
    <context-param>
            <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
            <param-value>Development</param-value>
        </context-param>

        <welcome-file-list>
            <welcome-file>/secured/secure.xhtml</welcome-file>
        </welcome-file-list>

        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>

        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>

        <context-param>
            <param-name>javax.faces.INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </context-param> 
    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
          <web-resource-name>Restricted</web-resource-name>
          <url-pattern>/secured/*</url-pattern>
          <http-method>GET</http-method>
          <http-method>POST</http-method>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
          <role-name>ADMIN</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
      </security-constraint>
<login-config>
     <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
     <realm-name>jdbc-realm</realm-name>
     <form-login-config>
       <form-login-page>/public/login.xhtml</form-login-page>
       <form-error-page>/public/error.xhtml</form-error-page>
     </form-login-config>
   </login-config>
```

I want my web app to redirect unauthorized users to login page. The funny thing i had this working but i made some stupid changes and now on accessing `localhost:8080` i always see secure.xhtml even when not logged in. `localhost:8080/secured/secure.xhtml` redirects fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are not using `<welcome-file>` entirely correctly. It should represent the sole filename of the file which needs to be served whenever a folder is been requested, irrespective of the requested folder (the root `/`, or `/public/` or `/secured/`, etc).

The welcome file is served by an internal forward as performed by [`RequestDispatcher#forward()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#forward%28javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse%29). Internal forwards do **not** trigger the security constraints. You need to send a redirect instead.

Change the `<welcome-file>` to a more sane default, e.g. `index.xhtml`.

```xml
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

And create one in the webapp's root like `/index.xhtml`. If you need to redirect *every* request on `/index.xhtml` to `/secured/secure.xhtml`, then there are basically 2 ways:

1. Map a [`Filter`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info) on the URL pattern of `/index.xhtml` and call [`response.sendRedirect("secured/secure.xhtml")`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendRedirect%28%29) inside the `doFilter()` method. E.g.

   ```java
   @WebFilter("/index.xhtml")
   public class IndexFilter implements Filter {

       @Override
       public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
           HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
           response.sendRedirect("secured/secure.xhtml"));
       }

       // ...
   }
   ```
2. Put a `<f:event type="preRenderView">` in the `/index.xhtml` which calls a backing bean method which in turn does a [`externalContext.redirect("secured/secure.xhtml")`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#redirect%28java.lang.String%29). E.g.

   ```html
   <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{indexBean.redirect}" />
   ```

   with

   ```java
   @ManagedBean
   @ApplicationScoped
   public class IndexBean {

       public void redirect() throws IOException {
           FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("secured/secure.xhtml");
       }

   }
   ```

Comment: Wow thanks! But what about checking if user is logged in? Should i do this in same filter? Is it's ok to take this away from container?

Comment: The `<security-constraint>` already does that. You don't need to do it yourself. The sole point is that you need to perform a redirect instead of a forward. A redirect creates a brand new request which will then trigger the security constraints again with the new URL. For a forward it's too late because the security constraints have *already* been tested based on the initial URL of `/` which is as per your configuration publicly accessible without constraints.

Comment: i have a trouble with filter. It seams if i have `security-constraint` filter is not called, if i comment out `constraint` it starts working. Maybe its because they are overlapping on /secured/* pages? Server - glassfish 3.1. Please, if you have time, help me out.

Comment: Apparently you've changed the URL pattern of the filter to the one which is matched by the security constraint, or you've changed the security constraint to match `/index.xhtml` as well. This is not the intention.

Comment: Big thanks, works perfectly. But i have 1 more question, if you don't mind: is it possible to map some filter to the same url-pattern as constraints and get it called before constraint, for example if i want to check cookie or something like that?